# How to access extension in Swift 4

Tags: swift

I'm a newbie and I could not find a beginner friendly explanation on how to do this.

I would like to access the below extension code from two different controllers (UIViewController and UITableViewControllers).

Questions: 
1. How can I access the extension code from ViewControllers?
2. How should I store the extension code as a file? What's a common pattern?

The extension I use allows me to slice string simply.

```
let str = "abc"
print(str[0]) // a
```

Below is the extension code

```
extension StringProtocol {
  subscript(offset: Int) -> Element {
        return self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: offset)]
    }

    subscript(_ range: CountableRange<Int>) -> SubSequence {
        return prefix(range.lowerBound + range.count)
            .suffix(range.count)
    }
    subscript(range: CountableClosedRange<Int>) -> SubSequence {
        return prefix(range.lowerBound + range.count)
            .suffix(range.count)
    }

    subscript(range: PartialRangeThrough<Int>) -> SubSequence {
        return prefix(range.upperBound.advanced(by: 1))
    }
    subscript(range: PartialRangeUpTo<Int>) -> SubSequence {
        return prefix(range.upperBound)
    }
    subscript(range: PartialRangeFrom<Int>) -> SubSequence {
        return suffix(Swift.max(0, count - range.lowerBound))
    }
}
```

I would like to access this from

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to copy paste this code to a file (maybe named as `StringExtensions.swift`)in your project. `StringProtocol` is a public protocol and you are extending it to increase the functionality of normal strings. You can than use it on any string inside your project and it will not be limited to a controller.